# how to make two networks connected with selected members

Tags: r, igraph

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(Core = c("Bestman", "Tetra"), member1 = c("Tera1", 
"Brownie1"), member2 = c("Tera2", "Brownie2"), member3 = c("Tera3", 
"Brownie3"), member4 = c("Tera4", "Brownie4"), member5 = c("Tera5", 
"Brownie5"), member6 = c("", "Brownie6"), member7 = c("", "Brownie7"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I want to connect all the members to their Core. for example if you look at the first row, you can see there are 5 members , I want to connect them to their Core
The same for the second row

Then I connect both Core together

Here is what I have done

```
mydf <- crossprod(table(cbind(df[1], stack(df[-1]))[-3]))
graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mydf, diag = F, weighted = T, mode = "undirected") %>% 
  plot(edge.width = E(.)$weight)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly, what you want is:

```r
library(igraph)

df<- data.frame(Core = c("Bestman", "Tetra"), member1 = c("Tera1", 
"Brownie1"), member2 = c("Tera2", "Brownie2"), member3 = c("Tera3", 
"Brownie3"), member4 = c("Tera4", "Brownie4"), member5 = c("Tera5", 
"Brownie5"), member6 = c("", "Brownie6"), member7 = c("", "Brownie7"))


edges <- t(do.call(rbind, apply(
    df, 1, function(x)  cbind(x[1], x[x!=""][-1])))) 

core_edges <- if(nrow(df)>1) combn(df$Core,2) else c()

g<-graph(c(edges,core_edges), directed=F )
plot(g , edge.width = E(g)$weight)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To colorize and resize nodes:

```
V(g)$color <- apply(df, 1, \(x) names(V(g)) %in% x) |> apply(1,which)
V(g)$size <- 15 
V(g)[df$Core]$size <- degree(g, V(g)[df$Core]) + 15
plot(g)
```

[image: colored graph]

Comment: can you help me have them in two different color? also is it possible to size the Core based on their member?

Comment: Hello nik, i added it to the example. I asume color based on their member refers to degree, i.e. number of edges adjacent to core nodes.

Comment: it is way better, open more request , is it possible to get ride or the names in the members ? just keep the names in the Core? I definitely accept and like your answer

Comment: my issue is that when the members gets more, it gets together and becomes ugly

Comment: You can set the $label of the vertices  only in "core"  to the names (ids) of the vertex: `V(g)[names(V(g)) %in% df$Core]$label <- names(V(g)[names(V(g)) %in% df$Core])`.  Then plot(g). if you set label to some vertices, hhose that are not set or set NA will remain with no labels. See `?igraph.plotting` for a full set of parameters.